# Can a MySQL database be corrupted in case the server shuts down?

Tags: apache-http-server, mysql

Say, a client browser is accessing my website and data is flowing between it and my backend MySQL server.  At this particular moment, a superuser on the server side issues an unscheduled system shutdown or scheduled cron job that results in a restart of LAMP stack (i.e., Apache, PHP-FQM and MySQL servers). Will that potentially corrupt the MySQL database?

What would be a good practice in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

This ** should** not cause any issues, for 2 reasons -

1. If a shutdown/restart command is issued, a signal is sent to the database server to allow it to get to a sane state before shutting down.
2. Modern databases (and filesystems) - including modern version of MySQL have a journaling system which ensure consistency in event if a sudden loss of power/shutdown.

Caveat - this answer assumes a properly written approval - one that, where a nber if changes need to be written as a single block - uses a transaction, and/or the database has appropriate consistency restraints. (If everything does not write, it rolls back). It is possible for a badly written app and database schema  to write a partial set of changes which can cause errors at the application level because assumptions about relationships if data are invalidated by some data being written - but this is nor technically data corruption.